# Docker container can not be found using curl

Tags: java, curl, docker

Using the curl command, `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json?all=1`, provided in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/), I get a JSON result with all containers on my machine.

```
[{"Id":"b20b26f300f86125466716cf70f3d105b7e55c7bef103276d6b4e6244a0fbd2e","Names":["/generated_898522226"],"Image":"nginx","ImageID":"sha256:eb4a127a1188a3e274eb38f079c5e11680b942927956a38b9b6b6c6736e14fd2","Command":"nginx -g 'daemon off;'","Created":1463082026,"Ports":[],"Labels":{},"State":"exited","Status":"Exited (0) 18 hours ago","HostConfig":{"NetworkMode":"default"},"NetworkSettings":{"Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"","EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":""}}},"Mounts":[]},{"Id":"dfe7908b7de93b0bfee8be0043e30f103e3f98bf1ec5cd04d569bf626449b23d","Names":["/generated_1639068228"],"Image":"nginx","ImageID":"sha256:eb4a127a1188a3e274eb38f079c5e11680b942927956a38b9b6b6c6736e14fd2","Command":"nginx -g 'daemon off;'","Created":1463081989,"Ports":[],"Labels":{},"State":"exited","Status":"Exited (0) 18 hours ago","HostConfig":{"NetworkMode":"default"},"NetworkSettings":{"Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"","EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":""}}},"Mounts":[]}]
```

However, when I execute the following command; `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/b20b26f300f8/start`, it tells me `404 page not found`. The id is there in the JSON result, how come it isn't found when I try to start it?

Comment: At least you get 404 and not a timeout or other connection error. Are you sure that page is correct?

Comment: Also, if you are using the start endpoint, you need a POST request to start the container

Comment: @cricket_007 if I place the full id or the name of the container, it still gives me 404. I can't think of anything else to place in that parameter.

Comment: You could be getting 404 because your cURL command makes GET requests, not POST requests. That endpoint may not allow GET requests

Comment: Try `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/b20b26f300f8/json` first. That inspects that one container

Comment: @cricket_007 Inspect does work tho. I am not sure how to make it a POST request. After adding -X POST, nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure the inspect works? You've only shown the all containers command in the question. I'm not sure what else to tell you, though. What if you give the container a name and use that instead of the id?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yup, inspect really works. It returns me a valid JSON object from the specified container (b20b26f300f8). How would I make it a POST curl request?

Comment: Should just be `curl -X POST url` like you had.